# Помогите просуммировать sql запросом

Tags: sql

Есть таблица вида:
Месяц    Значение
январь      6
январь      67
январь      12
февраль     34
февраль     11
март        22
март        3
март        14 
март        8
и т.д.      ...

результатом запроса должно быть такое:
Месяц      Значение
январь        85
февраль       45
март          29
и т.д.

т.е. нужно просуммировать значения по каждому месяцу, при чем, количество записей с одинаковым месяцем произвольно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю:

```
sql> select * from m_values
+---------+---------+
| m_name  | m_count |
+---------+---------+
| январь  | 6       |
| январь  | 67      |
| январь  | 12      |
| февраль | 34      |
| февраль | 11      |
| март    | 22      |
| март    | 3       |
| март    | 14      |
| март    | 8       |
+---------+---------+
```

Соответственно выражение:

```
sql> select m_name, sum(m_count) from m_values group by m_name
+---------+--------------+
| m_name  | sum(m_count) |
+---------+--------------+
| январь  | 85           |
| февраль | 45           |
| март    | 47           |
+---------+--------------+
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select month, count(*) from year group by month
```